# How MD5 and salt algorithms come into play if the attacker uses curl?

Tags: passwords, salt, md5

When the user logs into any site, they supply a username ('user01') and password ('password123') into a form then submit. The user has no idea what their hashed password value is that is stored in the database. The user just types 'password123' as password. If someone wants to brute force that account, they can just use a dictionary attack and post to the same login URL with `curl`. What then is the value of hashing your password at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what is the value of hashing your password at that point?

The value of hashing and salting passwords is not in brute-force attack "from outside", but when somebody breaks into your application or database (possibly other way) and wants to get users credentials.

If they would be stored without hashing, he can just read them which is not great since many users use the same password for many services. Hashing with md5 will make it only a bit more complicated because of Rainbow tables, but salting gives much more possible values and if attacker wants to get the passwords, he needs to do brute-force attack for every password, even though he knows the salt.

Comment: I understand that, but how does that protect you from dictionary attack?

Comment: It does not. It protects you against rainbow tables, basically.

Comment: So two factor authentication is the only way to safeguard against dictionary attacks?

Comment: No. Solution can be locking user or rather source of too many requests (because this can be also considered as DOS attack). 2FA mitigates it, by adding another complexity on which you can't use dictionary attack and which changes over time (faster than you can try).

Comment: Rather than locking you can use increasing delays or other throttling techniques to prevent a lockout while making a dictionary attack take a very long time.

Comment: Also note: if they steal the password file, there is typically many many users listed there.  If each has their own salt on their password, the dictionary attacker has to attack each password individually.  Without a salt, they get to attack all of them in parallel.